# MVC returns null instead of a IList<> object

Tags: c#, jquery, html, .net, model-view-controller

I am using MVC .NET 4.5 and my form returns a null instead of a List of objects. At the same time I have this Jquery function that adds HTML to the form, but it doesn't just adds the HTML, it makes the form POST to the controller. I don't know if both of these are related, but just in case I am providing all the relevant code. Please help.

Model class:

```
public class BidModels
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id{ set; get;}


    //Who put the bid...
    public string UserId { set; get; }

    //The Compnay putting the bid
    [ForeignKey("CompanyModels")]
    public int? CompanyId { set; get; }

    public virtual CompanyModels CompanyModels { set; get; }

    //The position being bid on
    [ForeignKey("ProjectPositionModels")]
    public int? PositionId { set; get; }

    public virtual ProjectPositionModels ProjectPositionModels { set; get; }

    //How much?
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public int? BidAmount { set; get; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddBid(IList<BidModels> bids)
{ 
    //Iterate the list for every new bid in it.
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var companyId = db.CompanyModels.Single(x => x.UserId == userId);


    //checking for content
    Console.Write(bids.ToString());
        //db.BidModels.Add();
       // await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return View("Index");
}
```

partial view:

```
    <form method="post" action="/BidModels/AddBid">

    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Make a Bid</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

            <div style="margin-left:15px;">
                <button id="add"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
                <button id="remove"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span></button>
            </div>


            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <table class="table" id="form-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Position</strong>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <strong>Bid Amount</strong>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="form-row">
                    <td>
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <input type="hidden" name="bid[0].Id" value="" />

                        <input type="hidden" name="bid[0].UserId" value="" />

                        <input type="hidden" name="bid[0].CompanyId" value="" />

                        @Html.DropDownList("bid[0].PositionId", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dlist" })

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid[0].BidAmount" />
                            <span class="input-group-addon ">.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $i = 0;
        var bid = $("#form-table");

        var dlist = $(".dlist").clone().attr("name", "bid[" + $i + "].PositionId");

        $("#add").click(function () {

            $i++;
            var id = '<input type="hidden" name="bid[' + $i + '].Id"/>';
            var userId = '<input type="hidden" name="bid[' + $i + '].UserId"/>';
            var companyId = '<input type="hidden"  name="bid[' + $i + '].CompanyId"/>';
            var bidAmount = '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-addon">$</span><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bid[' + $i + '].BidAmount"/></div>';

            bid.append("<tr><td id='mvc" + $i +"'>" + id + userId + companyId + "</td><td> " + bidAmount + " </td></tr>");
            $("#mvc" + $i + "").append(dlist.clone());
    });

    $("#remove").click(function () {
        if ($("#form-table tr").length > 2) {
            $i--;
            $("#form-table tr:last").remove();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using the name `bid` but your controller is expecting `bids`. Try making the parameter name for the action `bid` (or vice versa) and run it again.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid. I have been trying to figure it out for a while now. : (. Any idea why my jquery would call a POST from the view?

Comment: @user3394416 depending on the browser, a `button` without a `type` attribute will default to `type="submit"`. Try specifying `type="button"` on your "Add" button.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not idea that a button would be considered of type submit if not specified. I greatly appreciate your help.